# What is the difference between these two ArrayList methods?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, comparison

Shouldn't these essentially be the same? But only when I used the size variable and explicitly altered size did the code run as expected.

The following does not run as intended:

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> miembres)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < miembres.size() - 1; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < miembres.size(); j++)
    if(miembres.get(i).equals(miembres.get(j)))
    {
     miembres.remove(j);
     j--;
    }
    return miembres;
}
```

The following DOES run as intended:

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> miembres)
{
    int size = miembres.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
    if(miembres.get(i).equals(miembres.get(j)))
    {
     miembres.remove(j);
     size--;
     j--;
    }
    return miembres;
}
```

Shouldn't the for loop automatically account for the change in size?

Comment: Why you think both methods shoud be the same? In the second one you decement the size variable

Comment: It's usually bad practice to mutate a method parameter. So you should return a new list and not mutate the method parameter. If you are mutating the method parameter, your method should have void return type

Comment: Because shouldn't the for loop automatically check for changes in size and account for that with each iteration?

Comment: Side note: idents matter. The fact that you are NOT indenting your inner for loop and that if block makes your code 10 times harder to read than necessary. I would also suggest to always always put "body content" into { braces } to avoid that nasty problem when you want to add a second statement to the loop body, but you forgot to add the { braces } then.

Comment: And unless you are doing this for learning purposes, the "normal" way of eliminating duplicates is by turning your list into a set.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "does not run as intended"

Comment: Simple answer: When removing items, always iterate backwards (in your case in both loops), from `count-1` to 0. This solved all those problems. The other comments already laid out where the actual problem lies.

Comment: can you please provide an example when both code snippets results are different?

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, you compare `i` and `j` to `miembres.size()`, so even if the list's size is decreased, there's no special treatment required - it will be reflected in the call to `size()`.

In the second snippet, `size()` is called once and saved in a local variable that will no longer be effected by the changes in the list, so when you remove an item from it, you need to manually decrement that variable (done here by calling `size--`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me

The issue you're encountering is related to **modifying the size** of the ArrayList (miembres) while iterating over it. When you remove an element from the ArrayList inside the loop, the size of the ArrayList changes, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

In the first version of your code, you are directly modifying the ArrayList (miembres) within the loop, and this can cause elements to be skipped or the loop to iterate beyond the updated size of the ArrayList.

In the second version, you are storing the initial size of the ArrayList in a separate variable (size) and then decrementing it when you remove an element. This approach avoids the problem of modifying the ArrayList directly within the loop.

Comment: *This approach avoids the problem of modifying the ArrayList directly within the loop.* Errr, no. Both pieces of code shown here modify the list while iterating it. The only difference is in the checking of the loop condition.